# My code is coming up with the error "local variable 'total2' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried using globals (after about 10 minutes of searching around) and it didn't work. 
Still fairly new to code so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import random

def roll_die():
     roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
     roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
     total = roll1 + roll2
     if roll1 == roll2:
            roll3 = random.randint(1,6)
            total2 = total + roll3
     elif total == 2 or total == 4 or total == 6 or total == 8 or total == 10 or total == 12:
        total5 = total2 + 10
        print("The three dice came out with {}, {} and {}".format(roll1, roll2, roll3))
        return ("The total of the dice is {}".format(total5))
     else:
        total2 == 1 or total2 == 3 or total2 == 7 or total2 == 9 or total2 == 11 or total2 == 13
        total6 = total2 - 5
        print("The three dice came out with {}, {} and {}".format(roll1, roll2, roll3))
        return ("The total of the dice is {}".format(total6))


     if total == 2 or total == 4 or total == 6 or total == 8 or total == 10 or total == 12:
        total3 = total + 10
        print("The two dice came out with {} and {}".format(roll1, roll2))
        return ("The total of the dice is {}".format(total3))
     else:
        total == 1 or total == 3 or total == 7 or total == 9 or total == 11 or total == 13
        total4 = total - 5
        total4 < 0
        print("The two dice came out with {} and {}".format(roll1, roll2))
        return ("The total of the dice is {}".format(total4))

print(roll_die())
```

Comment: Simply you are using `total2` before being defined.

Comment: explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`total2` value is defined only if you enter the first statement. Otherwise, `total2` is not defined hence the error. You can try to give a default value to `total2` so it will be always defined, something like this :

```
 #...
 total = roll1 + roll2
 total2 = 0 #or any default value you want
 # ...
```